# When using purrr::map() to fit a model onto a new list-column, return indicative strings if fitting errors

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, tibble

I have data that I want to model per group using `purrr::map()`. Sometimes, fitting the model fails for one (or more) of the subgroups. The error could be, for example, `contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels`, or a warning such as `glm.fit: algorithm did not converge`, or otherwise.

Because an error fails the entire code, I'd like to create a condition: if there's a fitting error for a sub-group, return `"string-of-choice"` for that sub-group; but for sub-groups that do result with a model, for them return the model object. And even if there's a warning about convergence, I prefer having `"string-of-choice-2"` than a non-converging model.

While my question is general, I'm providing some example of toy data for demonstration.

### Example

Here's a function for generating data. In this data, 3 columns correspond to 3 questions that people answered about:

1. whether they love coconut (yes or no, coded as `0`/`1`.)
2. whether they love eggplant
3. whether they love tomatoes

In addition, we have an `id` column and `gender` column.

In the following two versions of this data, the column about loving tomatoes could be either all `NA` or all `0`.

```r
generate_data <- function(x) {
  data.frame(id = 1:2000, 
             do_u_love_coconut = sample(c(0, 1, NA), 2000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.2, 0.4, 0.4)),
             do_u_love_eggplant = sample(c(0, 1, NA), 2000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.4)),
             do_u_love_tomatoes = rep(x, 2000),
             gender = sample(c("male", "female"), 2000, replace = TRUE))
}

## generate the data
set.seed(2021)

df_tomatoes_is_NA   <- generate_data(NA)
df_tomatoes_is_zero <- generate_data(0)

## preview the data
library(tibble)

as_tibble(df_tomatoes_is_NA)
## # A tibble: 2,000 x 5
##       id do_u_love_coconut do_u_love_eggplant do_u_love_tomatoes gender
##    <int>             <dbl>              <dbl> <lgl>              <chr> 
##  1     1                NA                 NA NA                 male  
##  2     2                NA                 NA NA                 male  
##  3     3                NA                 NA NA                 male  
##  4     4                 1                  1 NA                 female
##  5     5                NA                  1 NA                 female
##  6     6                NA                 NA NA                 male  
##  7     7                NA                 NA NA                 female
##  8     8                 1                  1 NA                 male  
##  9     9                 0                  1 NA                 female
## 10    10                 0                  1 NA                 female
## # ... with 1,990 more rows

as_tibble(df_tomatoes_is_zero)
## # A tibble: 2,000 x 5
##       id do_u_love_coconut do_u_love_eggplant do_u_love_tomatoes gender
##    <int>             <dbl>              <dbl>              <dbl> <chr> 
##  1     1                NA                  0                  0 male  
##  2     2                NA                 NA                  0 male  
##  3     3                 1                 NA                  0 female
##  4     4                 0                  1                  0 female
##  5     5                 1                  0                  0 male  
##  6     6                NA                  0                  0 female
##  7     7                 1                  1                  0 male  
##  8     8                 1                 NA                  0 male  
##  9     9                 1                 NA                  0 male  
## 10    10                 0                  1                  0 female
## # ... with 1,990 more rows
```

---

**Fitting the model**

So now I want to fit a model of each coconut/eggplant/tomatoes by gender.

- *version 1 of the data*

```r
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

df_tomatoes_is_NA %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("do_u")) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(fit_and_predict = map(data,
                               ~ glm(formula = value ~ gender, data = .x, family = "binomial")))
```

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `fit_and_predict`.
>
> x contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
>
> i Input `fit_and_predict` is `map(data, ~glm(formula = value ~ gender, data = .x, family = "binomial"))`.
>
> i The error occurred in group 3: name = "do_u_love_tomatoes".

- *version 2 of the data*

```r
df_tomatoes_is_zero %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("do_u")) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(fit_and_predict = map(data,
                               ~ glm(formula = value ~ gender, data = .x, family = "binomial")))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   name [3]
  name               data                 fit_and_predict
  <chr>              <list>               <list>         
1 do_u_love_coconut  <tibble [2,000 x 3]> <glm>          
2 do_u_love_eggplant <tibble [2,000 x 3]> <glm>          
3 do_u_love_tomatoes <tibble [2,000 x 3]> <glm>
```

> Warning message:
>
> Problem with `mutate()` input `fit_and_predict`.
>
> i glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
>
> i Input `fit_and_predict` is `map(data, ~glm(formula = value ~ gender, data = .x, family = "binomial"))`.
>
> i The error occurred in group 3: name = "do_u_love_tomatoes".

---

### My question

I want to account for potential fitting errors and decide what should be the return value in such failures. For example, for an error such as `contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels` I want to have `"contrasts_error"` as the return value. An expected output for example:

```r
df_tomatoes_is_NA %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("do_u")) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(fit_and_predict = map(data,
                               ~ glm(formula = value ~ gender, data = .x, family = "binomial")))

## # A tibble: 3 x 3
## # Groups:   name [3]
##   name               data                 fit_and_predict
##   <chr>              <list>               <list>         
## 1 do_u_love_coconut  <tibble [2,000 x 3]> <glm>          
## 2 do_u_love_eggplant <tibble [2,000 x 3]> <glm>          
## 3 do_u_love_tomatoes <tibble [2,000 x 3]> <chr[1]> <-- "contrasts_error"
```

And if there's a convergence warning, for example `glm.fit: algorithm did not converge`, I'd like to have:

```r
df_tomatoes_is_zero %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("do_u")) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(fit_and_predict = map(data,
                               ~ glm(formula = value ~ gender, data = .x, family = "binomial")))

## # A tibble: 3 x 3
## # Groups:   name [3]
##   name               data                 fit_and_predict
##   <chr>              <list>               <list>         
## 1 do_u_love_coconut  <tibble [2,000 x 3]> <glm>          
## 2 do_u_love_eggplant <tibble [2,000 x 3]> <glm>          
## 3 do_u_love_tomatoes <tibble [2,000 x 3]> <chr[1]> <-- "convergence_warning"
```

---

EDIT

---

Just to clarify, since there are many potential fitting errors and warnings, a solution will always require me to specify in the code each potential error/warning and its respective string. I gave two examples above (contrasts error and convergence warning).

Comment: There could be many types of error/warnings that could occur. Do you want to capture each type and return a custom message if it occurs?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'll need to specify each error/warning and its respective string of choice.

Comment: In my mind this is similar to an if else conditioning. If error X then string `blah`, if error Y then string `foo`, if warning Z then string `foo foo`, and if a different error/warning then return a `"other_error_or_warning"` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle this with a `tryCatch` and capture all warnings and errors and return corresponding output for them.

```
apply_glm <- function(data, formula) {
  
  tryCatch(glm(formula = formula, data = data, family = "binomial"), error = function(e) {
    if(e$message == "contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels") 
      return('contrasts error')
  }, warning = function(w) {
    if(w$message == "glm.fit: algorithm did not converge")
      return('convergence warning')
  })
}
```

You can extend handling the error and warnings messages with `if`/`else if` or `case_when` statements.

Apply the function for dataset `df_tomatoes_is_NA` :

```
library(tidyverse)

df_tomatoes_is_NA %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("do_u")) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(fit_and_predict = map(data, apply_glm, value ~ gender)) -> result1
result1     

#  name               data                 fit_and_predict
#  <chr>              <list>               <list>         
#1 do_u_love_coconut  <tibble [2,000 × 3]> <glm>          
#2 do_u_love_eggplant <tibble [2,000 × 3]> <glm>          
#3 do_u_love_tomatoes <tibble [2,000 × 3]> <chr [1]>  

result1$fit_and_predict                              
[[1]]

Call:  glm(formula = value ~ gender, family = "binomial", data = data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)   gendermale  
    0.68837     -0.08838  

Degrees of Freedom: 1214 Total (i.e. Null);  1213 Residual
  (785 observations deleted due to missingness)
Null Deviance:      1564 
Residual Deviance: 1564     AIC: 1568

[[2]]

Call:  glm(formula = value ~ gender, family = "binomial", data = data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)   gendermale  
    1.61343     -0.01754  

Degrees of Freedom: 1218 Total (i.e. Null);  1217 Residual
  (781 observations deleted due to missingness)
Null Deviance:      1101 
Residual Deviance: 1101     AIC: 1105

[[3]]
[1] "contrasts error"
```

For dataset `df_tomatoes_is_zero` :

```
df_tomatoes_is_zero %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("do_u")) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(fit_and_predict = map(data,apply_glm)) -> result2
result2

#  name               data                 fit_and_predict
#  <chr>              <list>               <list>         
#1 do_u_love_coconut  <tibble [2,000 × 3]> <glm>          
#2 do_u_love_eggplant <tibble [2,000 × 3]> <glm>          
#3 do_u_love_tomatoes <tibble [2,000 × 3]> <chr [1]>    

result2$fit_and_predict
[[1]]

Call:  glm(formula = value ~ gender, family = "binomial", data = data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)   gendermale  
    0.49372      0.07442  

Degrees of Freedom: 1190 Total (i.e. Null);  1189 Residual
  (809 observations deleted due to missingness)
Null Deviance:      1570 
Residual Deviance: 1570     AIC: 1574

[[2]]

Call:  glm(formula = value ~ gender, family = "binomial", data = data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)   gendermale  
    1.60539     -0.03636  

Degrees of Freedom: 1177 Total (i.e. Null);  1176 Residual
  (822 observations deleted due to missingness)
Null Deviance:      1073 
Residual Deviance: 1073     AIC: 1077

[[3]]
[1] "convergence warning"
```

Comment: This is awesome, thank you! One question -- do you see a way to pass the formula to `apply_glm()` rather than have it hard-coded inside the function? In real data I'm likely to have many possible models/formulas, and I'd like to maintain only one `apply_glm()` function that can accept *any* formula.

Comment: Okay, I updated the answer to pass the formula to `apply_glm` function.